# Android: Changing coordinates into name of location or places

Tags: android, location

**What i have**: currently my app only receives latitude and longitude based on user input (user inputs the Latitude and Longitude of the preferred location)

**What i want**: my app to receive the name of location as user input..

How can i go about doing it?
Must i use database? Any preferred links(for tutorial)?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by the 'Name of the Location'.  As in; Do you mean Street Name?  Does the user put in a custom location for an area, Do you mean County, State, City or Country?  Or perhaps a business name/Street Address?  Your question is not very specific...  Do you want to save the users input (for later use) or just display it?

Comment: for the name of the location lets say a hospital. what i want is the name of departments within the hospital. so it is considered custom location..I just want to display user input by using a custom map...

Answer (score 1):

reverse Geo-Coding is very good, but you can only use this feature with Wifi connection. If your device is connect via Mobile Data connection (3G,EDGE), this service will not work.